# Rsync with ssh, job fails: Permission denied (13)

Tags: redhat, rsync

Recently my rsync job has been failing with the error shown below:

```
rsync: mkstemp "/foo/bar.txt" failed: Permission denied (13)
inflate returned -3 (0 bytes)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at token.c(548) [receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (10864 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
FAILED
```

I have checked file permissions on both the client and the server side and everything seems ok.

This used to work previously and there have been no significant configuration changes. I'm genuinely stumped and would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: > rsync /source/ foo@remote:/bar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cicero can u show the cmd that u r using on client & file permission on server side.

Generally this error comes when destination host or file path is not correct.

[check Ques3 here if it helps](https://rsync.samba.org/issues.html)

I don't have reputation to comment so replying through Answer.

Comment: See command above

Comment: this doesn't help to figure out the exact error. If u don't want to share the commands , kindly check the link for possible reason including disk space on server side, n/w issue etc.

Comment: Problem solved, it was a permissions error on the server side. `sudo chown -R user:group` fixed this for me. Thanks for taking the time to assist.

Comment: grt!! thnks for accepting as correct ans.